# Xpath to filter an xml according to multiple node values

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Library>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Physics</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Math</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Applied Math</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>1</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Chemistry</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Organic Chemistry</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>1</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Inorganic Chemistry</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>2</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
</Library>
```

in which I have to return (only) the Aisles that have the correctionNumber equal to the max(correctionNumber), considering the same sequenceNumber.
So in this example, I would have to return the following result:

```
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Physics</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Applied Math</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>1</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
   <Aisle>
      <Shelf>
         <Genre>Inorganic Chemistry</Genre>
         <sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber>
         <correctionNumber>2</correctionNumber>
      </Shelf>
   </Aisle>
```

I'm testing the xpath on https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.
My original idea was to use the `choose()` function, described on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/choose, so I could test if the value is lesser than the max(), but it seems like the `choose` function is not valid.
Does anyone knows an xpath that could evaluate the max value inside it, returning only the wanted nodes?

Comment: It's not clear where your are looking for any "max"; each `<Aisle>` has only one `<Shelf>` child node which in turn has only one `<correctionNumber>` child node. So what is the max calculated off of?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a Group by/Having structure you probably need to use an XPath processor with XQuery 3 support:

```
for $s in /Library/Aisle/Shelf
group by $seqNo := $s/sequenceNumber
return    $seqNo || ": " || max($s/correctionNumber) || " " || $s/Genre
```

Which gives us the expected columns (using custom output):

```
0: 0 Physics
1: 1 Math
2: 2 Chemistry
```

[Online Demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0A%3CLibrary%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EPhysics%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E0%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E0%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EMath%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E1%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E0%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EApplied%20Math%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E1%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E1%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EChemistry%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E2%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E0%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EOrganic%20Chemistry%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E2%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E1%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%3CAisle%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CGenre%3EInorganic%20Chemistry%3C%2FGenre%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CsequenceNumber%3E2%3C%2FsequenceNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CcorrectionNumber%3E2%3C%2FcorrectionNumber%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FShelf%3E%0A%20%20%20%3C%2FAisle%3E%0A%3C%2FLibrary%3E&=Genre&extract=for%20%24s%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FAisle%2FShelf%0Agroup%20by%20%24seqNo%20%3A%3D%20%24s%2FsequenceNumber%0Areturn%20%20%20%20%24seqNo%20%7C%7C%20%22%3A%20%22%20%7C%7C%20max(%24s%2FcorrectionNumber)%20%7C%7C%20%22%20%22%20%7C%7C%20%24s%2FGenre&=for%20%24s%20in%20%2FLibrary%2FAisle%2FShelf%0Agroup%20by%20%24seqNo%20%3A%3D%20%24s%2FsequenceNumber%0Areturn%20%20%20%20%24seqNo%20%7C%7C%20%22%3A%20%22%20%7C%7C%20max(%24s%2FcorrectionNumber)%20%7C%7C%20%22%20%22%20%7C%7C%20%24s%2FGenre&input-format=xml&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=xquery3.0)